# I have to divide the following $\frac{2x^3-9x^2+10}{2x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{2x^3-9x^2+10}{2x-1}$

> i can write 2${x^3}$- 9${x^2}$ +10 as 2${x^3}$-${x^2}$-10${x^2}$+10 but not sure it works.

Comment: You can write $2x^3-9x^2+10$ as $2x^3\color{red}{+}x^2-10x^2+10$ or as $2x^3-x^2-\color{red}{8}x^2+10$... this doesn't seem to help much though.

Comment: Use long division.

Comment: @arctictern In case you haven't noticed, what he has got going here is the beginnings of long division, but within the fraction notation that the OP is probably slightly familiar with. I'm all for that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \frac { 2x^{ 3 }-9x^{ 2 }+10 }{ 2x-1 } &=\frac { 2x^{ 3 }-8x^2-4x-{ x }^{ 2 }+4x+2+8 }{ 2x-1 } \\ &=\frac { 2x\left( { x }^{ 2 }-4x-2 \right) -\left( { x }^{ 2 }-4x-2 \right) +8 }{ 2x-1 } \\ &=\frac { \left( 2x-1 \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }-4x-2 \right) +8 }{ 2x-1 } \\ &=\left( { x }^{ 2 }-4x-2 \right) +\frac { 8 }{ 2x-1 } \end{align*} $$

Comment: @JMoravitz,thank you for mention

Answer (score 2):

It works wonders (but be careful that $-9x^2=-x^2-8x^2$, not $10$)! You have $$\frac{2x^3-9x^2+10}{2x-1}=\frac{2x^3-x^2-8x^2+10}{2x-1}\\=\frac{2x^3-x^2}{2x-1}+\frac{-8x^2+10}{2x-1}=x^2 +\frac{-8x^2+10}{2x-1}$$Now keep going, doing the same thing to the numerator that is left as you did before: by splitting $0x$ into $nx-nx$, where $n$ is the number that makes the next division go smoothly.